# uinavigationbar background image hides title

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, title

When i add background image to `uinavigationbar` it hides my title on `uinavigationbar`,

**Here is my code,**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
       ...
       ...

     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"BarBg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

**Code in Class:**

```
    int height = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    int width = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;

    UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    navLabel.text=@"Categories";
    navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    navLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
```

After writing this code i am unable to see title on navigation bar, title is behind navigationBar image.

**Please help, Thanks in advance..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of set label as a titleView of `UINavigationBar` add that `UILabel` as a Subview of NavigationBar like bellow...

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navLabel];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:navLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking only to customize your navigationBar title, I recommend using the appearance instead of adding a label to your navbar.

```
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:yourFontName size:fontSize],
                                 UITextAttributeTextColor :[UIColor whiteColor],

      }];
```